# android sql insert represent object to_date('30/03/2012','DD/MM/YYYY')

Tags: android, sql, date, ormlite

I try to execute 
      INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (2,'Qandahar','AFG','Qandahar',237500,to_date('30/03/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'));

For that i have class

```
package com.airliquid.android.backend.donnee.domainobject;

import java.sql.Date;

 import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;
import com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable;
 @DatabaseTable(tableName = "City")
 public class UserDo {
 @DatabaseField(generatedId=true,unique=true)
 private Long id;
 @DatabaseField(columnName="Name")
 private String Name;
 @DatabaseField(columnName="CountryCode")
 private String CountryCode;
 @DatabaseField(columnName="District")
 private String District;
 @DatabaseField(columnName="Population")
 private Long Population;

 @DatabaseField(columnName="date")
 private Date date;

}
```

When i execute without to_date('30/03/2012','DD/MM/YYYY') it's work, what object in android is to_date('30/03/2012','DD/MM/YYYY') ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the format SQL Lite is expecting is 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

If you want to convert a date to a String that SQL will understand use these lines of code:

> SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
>
> String date = sdf.format(YourDate);

YourDate is a Date variable containing the value you want to store (in your case 30/03/2012). Use constructor Date(int year, int month, int day).

Comment: I have a file that contains all this insert, and i have a for that insert all this lines dao.updateRaw(strLin);  

strLin = INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (2,'Qandahar','AFG','Qandahar',237500,to_date('16/09/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'));

Comment: this line of inserts is already defined in a file, how can i resolve this problem ?

Comment: What do you mean about "is already defined in a file"?

You should be able to modify the lines of code you are programming, right? If not, tell the owner of the code to modify it.

Be aware of the differences between SQL and SQLite.

Comment: @tamtoum1987 - If your import file has values in a format that is not compatible with your database then you ***do not*** do this in a single step.  In preference you should pre-parse your import file and translate the values to the correct format.  Alternatively, standard practice is to import the file in to a Staging Table and then propagate the contents of that table to your persisted table.  In your case you could insert the date as a varchar field, then when propagating it to the persisted table apply string manipulations, type casts, etc, to convert that in to a true date data-type.